# Efficient representation of data in a datastructure

Tags: java, optimization, data-structures

I have the following format:

```
SOLEXA3_1:3:5:1473:616/1    gi|7367913151|ref|NC_007367.1|  100.00  23  0   0   27  49  3404561 3404539 1e-5    46.1
SOLEXA3_1:3:5:1473:616/1    gi|73921565|ref|NC_007367.1|    100.00  23  0   0   27  49  3404561 3404539 1e-5    46.1
SOLEXA3_1:3:5:1474:616/1    gi|32140171|ref|NC_007367.1|    100.00  23  0   0   27  49  3404561 3404539 1e-2    46.1
SOLEXA3_1:3:5:1474:616/1    gi|7354921565|ref|NC_007367.1|  100.00  23  0   0   27  49  3404561 3404539 1e-5    46.1
SOLEXA3_1:3:5:1475:616/1    gi|73921565|ref|NC_007367.1|    100.00  23  0   0   27  49  3404561 3404539 1e-5    46.1
SOLEXA3_1:3:5:1475:616/1    gi|73921565|ref|NC_007367.1|    100.00  23  0   0   27  49  3404561 3404539 1e-5    46.1
```

Basically it is a tab-delimited file and I will have multiple hits for inputs (the first field: `SOLEXA3_1:3:5:1474:616/1` as an example) and multiple hits for a particular input: 
`32140171` and `7354921565` for the aforementioned example input).  What I want to do is build some sort of in-memory representation of all hits for a particular read and the quality associated with every hits - it is the penultimate field - `1e-5` and `1e-2` for the aforementioned 2 hits. So what I have done is the following:

I have a `Map<String, ArrayList<TObjectDoubleMap<String>>>`. Where every String is basically the input ID and the ArrayList consists of a map from the [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) library which holds a pair of String, double - the string being the Id of the hit and the score. My input file is around 18 millions of lines and with a heap of -Xmx12g I'm getting heap out of memory. Any ideas how I can optimize the memory usage? Bear in mind that the actual scores would vary so I don't think sharing them is feasible.

Comment: Is this for report? can afford a table for this? If so, you can use sqlloader.

Comment: Your explanation presumes too much familiarity with the domain of bioinformatics - 'hits', for example.

Comment: Also, it's not clear why you need a list of maps. Why not just a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
Map<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> map = new HashMap<String, ByteArrayOutputStream>();
```

Where the Key is simply a concatenation of the 2 fields, and you write the quality and score's to the ByteArrayOutputStream.

The resulting data structure would look something like:

```
Key:    "SOLEXA3_1:3:5:1474:616/1_32140171"
Value:  |5|46.1|2|46.1|  //where this is actually just a byte[]
```

Then when reading the qualities and scores you just use readByte() and readDouble() until you get to the end of the stream.

Of course, doing it this way makes querying stuff a little trickier, but you will save huge on memory allocation.

Ex:

```
for ( String[] fields : rows ) {
    Map<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> map = new HashMap<String, ByteArrayOutputStream>();
    String key = fields[0] + "_" + fields[1];
    byte quality = Byte.parseByte(fields[10].substring(3));
    double score = Double.parseDouble(fields[11]);

    if ( !map.containsKey(key) ) {
        map.put(key, new ByteArrayOutputStream());
    }
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(map.get(key));
    dos.writeByte(quality);
    dos.writeDouble(score);
}


//reading
for ( String key : map.keySet() ) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = map.get(key);
    int numHits = baos.size()/9; //1 byte for quality, 8 for score
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
    System.out.print( key + " - " + numHits);
    while ( din.available() > 0 ) {
        byte quality = din.readByte();
        double score = din.readDouble();
        System.out.print(" (" + quality + ", " + score + ")");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Using this method I can read and store ~20mil records in <1GB of memory. (In around 10 seconds on a MacBook Pro).

Comment: implemented this approach along with some suggestions by @tom anderson and now it works with 1 gig of heap. AWESOME! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach of using a map of lists is basically good, but could be engineered to be more compact.

Firstly, make sure you are canonicalising the read names. That is, there should only be one instance of a string with the characters "SOLEXA3_1:3:5:1473:616/1" in memory; use a map to reduce the names to a canonical instance before using them.

Secondly, are the hit identifiers always integers? If so, store them as such (as longs, since some are evidently too big to fit in ints).

Thirdly, i think you can store the hits and their scores in a very compact structure, as long as you're prepared to do some work, by manually packing both into a long (!). Then, you can just store a sorted array of longs for each input.

Here's how i'd canonicalise the read names:

```
Map<String, String> names = new HashMap<String, String>();

public String getCanonicalInstanceOfName(String name) {
    String canonicalName = names.get(name);
    if (canonicalName != null) {
        name = canonicalName;
    }
    else {
        names.put(name, name);
    }
    return name;
}
```

I can think of at least one smarter way to do this, but this will do for now.

Here's how i'd handle the hit scoring:

```
public long packHitIDAndScore(String id, float score) {
    long numericID = Long.parseLong(id);
    int scoreAsHundredthsOfAPercent = (int)(score * 100.0);
    long packedIDAndScore = (numericID << 14) + scoreAsHundredthsOfAPercent;
    return packedIDAndScore;
}
```

The 14 there is because 14 binary bits are big enough to hold values up to 16384, which is enough to contain the range 0 to 10000. Note that you only get 50 bits of storage for the ID, so it would be worth checking that no ID was bigger than 1125899906842623.

Since you're using Trove, you can store the packed longs in a TLongArrayList. Keep the list sorted by using binarySearch to find the appropriate place for each long joining the list, and insert to put it there. To look up a value in the list, use a binarySearch again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In fact there is only one instance of the SOLEXA3_1:3:5:1473:616/1 in the outer map because I first check if I have such a key if yes - then I just parse the hit ID and the score and add a map of them to the array list. but even with this I get out of heap space.

Comment: I should have realised you would already be doing that. Dumb suggestion on my part. My second suggestion, about storing the hits and scores more compactly, should still be relevant. I would estimate that a map entry with a 1o-character string and a double takes up 76 bytes; a packed double will take up 8 bytes, and so use around 10% of the memory. That should be a considerable saving.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options available for this but I would use an embedded database (but only if a "traditional" database is out of question) - [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), for instance. Unless you're doing so very heavy computations on the resulting data, that would be a safe bet.

Just a quick list of other options:

- ETL systems (granted that it requires a database)
- NIO if the out of memory is happening because of the way the file is being read
- "Lighter" data-structures (tries?, [FastUtil](http://fastutil.dsi.unimi.it/))

You may even use a combination of them all.